# Highchart Map Point chart city

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, maps

I am currently working on Highcharts Maps.

I am building an India Map and where i have to categorize cities in to two categories. i.e In primary category there are 16 centers and in secondary there are 12.

Do anyone have idea how to do that using highchart maps 
Some reference are

1) http://www.highcharts.com/samples/view.php?path=maps/demo/category-map

Comment: Simply see [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon) - it is almost exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @PawełFus it doesnt have options to categorize cities into two categories. i.e In legend area i want to show two categories instead of Cities. U can refer my provided reference

Comment: Simply create two series for mappoints, see: http://jsfiddle.net/73cz91dd/

Comment: thank you i was looking for dat only..@PawełFus

Comment: @PawełFus is there any way to automatically take places in map without providing lat,long?

Comment: See another [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/geojson-multiple-types). Also, don't forget to reed [this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/adding-points-and-lines).

Comment: @PawełFus its still not working.  i am trying to fetch cities from mysql, and plotting all those city list with mappoints  will a long tidy work. Can u suggest me some other solution?

Comment: What is not working? The demos I sent you are fine..

Comment: @PawełFus ya it is fine. But when i load my ajax data which includes cities name, so plotting each of the using mappoint is not possible.

Comment: But only city name is not enough to plot city marker in a correct place. You need x+y (map positions) or lat+long(global positions).